# Add cancel header to the HyperlinkTheme.xml file

Tags: wix, wix3.6

Is there is any way to add a cancel event header to the theme file, so that i can configure the user cancellation event and display an appropriate message. so far i am getting a setup failed message even if the user cancelled the installation or any other failure occurred.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the text on the confirmation message box displayed when the user clicks the cancel button. To do so, provide a custom `.wxl` file and change the `ConfirmCancelMessage` string. The default is:

```
<String Id="ConfirmCancelMessage">Are you sure you want to cancel?</String>
```

(See the `src\ext\BalExtension\wixstdba\Resources\*.wxl` files for examples).

However, in wixstdba, when the user clicks the cancel button during Apply(), wixstdba will always go to the failure page. That or the success page are the only two options today. There has been some discussion about extending the failure page to be more customizable but no work has been done on that idea.